# Fixture not found although it exist in conftest.py

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

This is my test class:

```
import pytest


class TestInstallation:
    def test_some(self, fix_test):
        print(fix_test)
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture()
def fix_test():
    return 123
```

And when I try to run my test I received this `error`:

> ```
> > def test_install(self, fix_test): E       fixture 'fix_test' not found
> > >       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig,
> > record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute,
> > recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
> > >       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
> ```

When I put my `fixture` inside my test class this works fine.

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I think you have to list `foo` in the test’s call signature

Comment: I did not see this test’s call signature in the examples on the web, any example ?

Comment: I don’t understand your comment. You created a fixture called `foo` but never used it. Then you tried to use a fixture called `fix_test` without defining it. What do you actually want to do?

Which one are you asking about?

Comment: typo... I edit my question

Comment: Try removing the parentheses from the fixture decorator

Comment: Still not found

Comment: BTW the usage above the fixture function exist, I mean I can see that my class function call it

Comment: What’s your directory structure?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, probably `conftest.py` is not in the correct place?

Comment: conftest.py in under tests directory and my tests class in under directory under tests directory